# What is the meaning of "morning blues" or "Monday blues"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Just want to know the real meaning of:

> Morning blues

or

> Monday blues

Do these two have the same meaning?

Comment: Morning laziness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The noun 'blues' refer to 'sad' feeling. This could be due to anything -laziness, no interest etc. It has nothing to do with the color 'blue'. [If you have blues, you feel sad.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/have-the-blues)

The commonest use is 'Monday Blues' referring to laziness one gets to get to work (as they just enjoyed 'work-free' weekends).

If you say, "Morning blues" probably it means the morning you don't feel to do anything. No zeal, no enthusiasm.

Does this two mean the same? **No**, they don't. One talks about Monday, and another talks about the morning.

Answer (score 4):

Monday morning blues and Morning blues are two different situations but the word 'blues' mean the same. Blue refers to the lack of joy, laziness, tiredness, stress, etc. Monday morning blues is the feeling that comes to us as the weekend has passed by and it is time to resume the work again. 'Monday'is the universal start of week day in all countries across the globe except for the GCC countries. Morning blues is a feeling which can come on any random day, not only due to work but also due to some other reasons. Never confuse yourself with 'Monday Morning Blues' and 'Morning Blues' as there are a lot of differences between the two idioms.

Answer (score 3):

The term "blues" in each expression means the same. It is sadness, coupled with some lethargy. In fact this answer from yahoo dot com ([What is the meaning of monday blues?](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090424232310AABeolA)) contains a very good explanation, and it summarizes Monday Blues as

> To put all these together, we can define MONDAY BLUES as:
>   The low-spirited, cool, annoyed, sad, unlucky mood of those workers, students, or employees who feel that a mundane, difficult, unexpected Weekday is arriving to force them into going back to work, killing their joys and annoying them.

except that I would take out "unexpected" from that list.

The main meaning of blues is sadness, or expressing sadness. Not laziness. But sadness, or feeling really blue, contains an element not of laziness but lethargy, or lack of energy.

This is true whether it is Monday Blues or Morning Blues.

In fact, if you say that *someone has got the blues*, it means he is sad or moody or depressed.

If you feel only laziness, you do not have the blues.

Here is a good article:
[Definitive Guide To Beat The Monday Blues & Kick Start Your Week](http://smilepls.com/answers/beat-the-monday-blues-kick-start-your-week.html?ref=ya)

Answer (score 0):

I would argue. The word "blues" has a lot to do with the color. Me personally went through a clinical depression, I have bipolar disorder, and I can tell that there is a HUGE difference in the perception of colors between normality (euthymia) and depression as well as between euthymia and mania. When I was clinically depressed, my visual perception virtually lost it's hue and vibrancy, so I was perceiving each color almost similarly, like in black and white, but there still was some "color"...Let's call it blue. Difficult to explain to people without this experience.

Comment: For this to be 'true' we need more evidence than your personal anecdote. I'm not belitlling what you experienced, but boldly stating that the word *has* to do with color needs more facts.

Answer (score 0):

Monday blues often refers to the comedown period after taking drugs such as MDMA. Often people will catch up on sleep on the Sunday, leaving Monday with a period mild depression or moodiness.

Comment: A source, please? This is sound reasoning, up to a point, but it seems simpler than that — that you’re unhappy for the simple reason that it’s Monday.